# How to print the contents of a screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, printing

is there a way to print the contents of a screen, that contain images rendered, to a printer in **React Native**?  I looked into **react-native-print** but it only accepts HTML text whilst **react-native-xprinter** only supports Android. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution? If so please guide me.

Comment: See my comment below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Managed to make it work.  See codes below.

```
import RNPrint from 'react-native-print';

var htmlString = `<div style="(your CSS style here)"> (HTML contents here) </div>`;

RNPrint.print({html: htmlString});
```

If you want to embed an image in the HTML, see below:

```
var htmlString = `<div style="(your CSS style here)"> 
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, ${imgData}" style="width: $imgWidth; height: $imgHeight"/>
</div>`;
```

You can replace "image/png" with other image type.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Jason, I have a screen which will be changing dynamically based on data. I need to print that screen. Can I achieve using this npm module?

Comment: Yes.  All you need to do is to construct the `htmlString` dynamically based on the data you want to print.

Comment: @Jason Hi Jason, I try to set the ${imgData} with `defaultLogo` that is from import defaultLogo from '../../assets/images/logo_default.png';, but the img is not working.  My issue like https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-print/issues/65, thanks in advance.

Comment: @徐博俊 Not tried `import defaultLogo` before.  Make sure the image is not null and is **serialized**.  For reference, you may refer to the `toDataUrl` method from the `react-native-qrcode-svg` package.

Comment: I find use filePath instead of html will work. Thanks for your reply.